# Google Analytics: regex for all URLs in a subdirectory

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm creating a custom report in Google Analytics.

I'd like the report to be filtered for all Page URLs that match:

`/flipbook/portfolio/*`

I've tried entering the filter for Include Page where regex `/[\/flipbook\/portfolio\/]/`, but this returns no hits in the report.

[image]

I'm confident we have received hits.

Comment: `[abc]` is a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) which matches a single letter (a, b, or c). Try removing the brackets.

Comment: It seems that a tutorial in regular expressions would be a useful step for you. Then try to make a regex which matches exactly one of the subdirectories. Pay special attention to the concept of character classes (see Tims comment above). Also to the concept of number specification, which in your case looks probably like `{1,}`. Also important to know is the concept of regular expression "flavors". Which means that when you learned something about regexes, you sometimes need to find out how to phrase it specifically for the regex-engine you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors to be fixed, and a recommendation to be used, to get the desired result.

- You should not include the trailing `/` sign in you regex in Google Analytics. Just the expression is required.
- The `[` and `]` signs mean a single character from the enclosed group. So currently this expression would match a single character present in the list: `\/flipbook\/portfolio\/`
- To precisely match the required path, if this is the beginning of the page path, you should use the start of string token (`^`)

So I'd recommend the following regular expression:

```
^\/flipbook\/portfolio\/
```